# how to put a description on my image slider android?

Tags: android

i have implemented a viewpager as imageslider and i created a page adapter and i pass my images to view pager and show them carefully and also i used a page indicator and it also works fine
so i need to implement a text description on bottom of my project that changes when my view pager slides

i have seen this project on the Github and i want to implement some thing like this
so how can i do something like this description with that animation?i mean i want when i change a page , the description with this animation come up and show a text on bottom of imageslider

just like this [project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIesu.gif)!

please see this image and look at the description animation on the bottom of image slider that shows Game of Thrones,...

this is my adapter :

```
 class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Context mContext;
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
int[] mResources = {
        R.drawable.q,
        R.drawable.r,
        R.drawable.w,
};


public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mResources.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);
    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)          {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
 }  
}
```

and i need to implement it on view pager with something special in my adapter with that beautiful animation

please help me!!

Comment: If you want to use the same kind of animation and viewpager. You can refer https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

Comment: @Fahim friend i knew this, but i want the idea of implementing this type of animation , this code is so complex, i need something easier